# Image change with status change

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to get the door's image to change from a closed door svg image to an open door svg image
when the status goes from closed to open in my home automation dashboard. Seeking help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <!-- Add font from Google fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Link CSS style sheet to html document -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!-- Link JavaScript file to html document -->
    <script src="mqttws31.js"></script>
    <script src="dashboard.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Home Automation Dashboard</h1>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="messages"></div>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <hr>
    <ul class="dashboard">
      <li class="dashboard_item kitchen">
        <h4>Kitchen</h4>
     <img src="./moon.svg" width="40px" id="toggle-img" height="40px" alt="">
        <p id="kitchen-light">OFF</p>
        <button id="kitchen-btn">Toggle</button>
      </li>
        <li class="dashboard_item frontdoor" > 
        <h4>Front Door</h4>
    <img src="./door-closed.svg" width="40px" id="toggle-img6" height="40px" alt="">
        <p id="frontdoor-door">CLOSED</p>
      </li>
     </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is what I've been trying in javascript:

```
function togglefrontdoor() {
  var status = document.getElementById("frontdoor-door").innerHTML;
  if (status === "CLOSED")
    document.getElementById('toggle-img6').innerHTML = './door-closed.svg';
  else if (status === "OPEN")
     document.getElementById('toggle-img6').innerHTML = './door-open.svg';
}
```

Comment: Wrong property, you should use `src` instead of `innerHTML`  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_src.asp

Comment: @Zeikman Still no change.

Comment: it's ok, let me show you an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the example which toggle the image button by reusing part of your element.

Click the ***Toggle*** button to switch the svg.

Your `togglefrontdoor()` is not really functioning well because the content of `toggle-img6` is always **CLOSED**, you need to update it as well while updating the svg.

Or maybe you have another function that call `togglefrontdoor()` like, I don't know

```
function toggleStatus() {
  // changing status ...
  ...

  togglefrontdoor();
}
```

But anyhow, I modify your `togglefrontdoor()` function just to make the example works.

Happy coding!

```html
<img src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/410.svg" width="40px" id="toggle-img6" height="40px" alt="">
<p id="frontdoor-door">CLOSED</p>
<button id="toggle-btn" onclick="togglefrontdoor()">Toggle</button>

<script>
function togglefrontdoor() {
  var frontdoor = document.getElementById("frontdoor-door");
  var img6 = document.getElementById('toggle-img6');
  var status = frontdoor.innerHTML;
  
  if (status === "CLOSED") {
    img6.src = 'https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg';
    frontdoor.innerHTML = 'OPEN';
  } else if (status === "OPEN") {
    img6.src = 'https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/410.svg';
    frontdoor.innerHTML = 'CLOSED';
  } else {
    // coding ...
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<img src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/410.svg" width="40px" id="toggle-img6" height="40px" alt="">
<p id="frontdoor-door">CLOSED</p>
<button id="toggle-btn" onclick="togglefrontdoor()">Toggle</button>

<script>
function togglefrontdoor() {
  var frontdoor = document.getElementById("frontdoor-door");
  var img6 = document.getElementById('toggle-img6');
  var status = frontdoor.innerHTML;
  
  if (status === "CLOSED") {
    img6.src = 'https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg';
    frontdoor.innerHTML = 'OPEN';
  } else if (status === "OPEN") {
    img6.src = 'https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/410.svg';
    frontdoor.innerHTML = 'CLOSED';
  } else {
    // coding ...
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.